# Binding input to an image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an image to which I need to glue an input field. There will be several input fields and each of them should always be in its place, namely on a certain part of the image.

```css
.input-circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<img class="figure-img img-fluid rounded" src="123.png"/>
<input class="form-control input-circle">
```

I need to do as shown in gif

[perfect result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1H8s.gif)

how can i bind input fields to image like that?
Or maybe I need to use a completely different concept?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You can use [background image](https://jsbin.com/duqifoy/edit?html,css,output) if needed. But if you can achieve this UI with only css (which I think you do if you have the fonts as web fonts) I'd prefer that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use position relative and absolute to achieve this. A little example:

```css
.body_wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.input_wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}

.input_wrapper .input-circle{
  height: 100%;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="body_wrapper">
  <div class="image_wrapper">
    <img src="https://cdn.britannica.com/s:800x450,c:crop/96/177096-138-2CB46AEC/discussion-organ-systems-human-body-another-influence.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  
  <div class="input_wrapper">
    <input class="form-control input-circle">
  </div>
</div>
```

[Working **fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/8d91h70c/1/)

Comment: Thanks, it works. But what about changing the resolution? so that the input field remains in its place. My image is reduced depending on the size of the screen.

Comment: This is just an example. I gave you the idea that how it'll work. You have to adjust `left`,  `right`, `top`, `bottom` according to the position the `body`

Comment: @RuslanAbdulloev please accept the answer if it helps

Comment: Thank you friend!